# Exact method that get called when a fragment in tab view is scrolled in

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tabview

Can anyone tell me what is the exact method or way to catch when the fragment is swiped in within the tabs view pager

Comment: What do you mean by scrolled?  i.e. you are vertically scrolling the fragment or you are horizontally swiping between fragments / tabs?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I have edited it, i mean when i swipe between tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your sliding tab layout, you can set an onPageChangeListener that will invoke a method each time the user swipes to a different page.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, i have edited my question, because i mean swipe between fragments